# Баг Firefox с AngularJS. 3 знака после запятой конвертируется в целое число

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend, firefox

Существует проблема только в браузере Firefox. При вводе числа c тремя знаками после запятой в input type="number" браузер Firefox конвертирует его в целое число.

Например, вводим

```
0.555
```

и AngularJS отображает нам

```
555
```

Код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="">
    <p>Input: <input type="number" ng-model="number"></p>
    <h1>Number {{number}}</h1>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

В других браузерах всё работает корректно. Есть ли варианты исправить эту проблему без использования input type="text"?

Comment: Ставьте запятую а не точку, все будет нормально. https://screenshots.firefox.com/4bAHsnWZwkae7u5F/ru.stackoverflow.com